# SQL Server CmdExec send output text when error occurs

Tags: sql-server, sql-job

I have a SQL Server Job that executes a batch file: Type = Operation System (CmdExex). The batch file echos a bunch of information as it runs, and the job is configured to send an email if the script fails. The email it sends looks like:

```
JOB RUN:    'MyJob' was run on 6/19/2013 at 10:30:00 AM
DURATION:   0 hours, 0 minutes, 10 seconds
STATUS:     Failed
MESSAGES:   The job failed.  The Job was invoked by Schedule 12 (Hourly on the half).  The last step to run was step 1 (Execute MyBatchFile).
```

Is there a way to get the above email to include the output of the batch file, which is what indicates the exact nature of the issue? I currently log the batch file output to a text file, which requires logging into the server to determine the issue. It would be quicker if the email just had this info already in it.

Answer (score 0):

Set the "On Failure" action for the job step to execute a new job step that emails the output from the batch file. If you want, you can have this new job step fail the job when it completes successfully or fails.